# How to handle org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException during xslt transform?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I want to execute xslt transform and handle all errors, if possible. But this piece of code

```
        transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
```

doesn't throws an exception, but prints following to console:

```
Неизвестный ИД системы; Номер строки 7; Номер столбца 40;        org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Переменная site_name не найдена

(in English this means Unknown ID system line number 7, column number 40;   org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: site_name variable was not found)
```

How can I force newTransformer throw an exception or collect these errors after function is done?
Haven't found any valuable info on the net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about throwing the exception, but you can collect them with an ErrorListener.
Something along these lines:

```
class ErrorCollector implements ErrorListener {

    private List<TransformerException> errors = new ArrayList<TransformerException>();

    @Override
    public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
        errors.add(exception);
    }

    ...
}
```

(the code is not complete, but I think you get the picture)

Then add it to your factory:

```
ErrorCollector errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();
factory.setErrorListener(errorCollector);
```

And access to the errors in the collector after that.

Hope it helps!